# How to properly call both TAP and non-TAP methods from same code?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, tap, async-ctp

I have class method A that needs to use the services of one of N calculator objects to do its job.

To keep A dumb and happy, I'm not going to ask it to figure out which calculator it needs to use; some higher level code is going to figure out which calculator A should be using, and inject it into A.

The problem I'm running in to is that some of these calculators are just hunks of non-TAP (sync code) and other calculators are methods that are marked "async" (TAP)

I can't figure out how to inject A with both TAP and non-TAP calculators. IE, for TAP calculators, it seems I need to do an "await", but for non-TAP calculators, I wouldn't.

Not sure how to approach this problem?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, if you're trying to move to an async model, I would recommend wrapping your synchronous methods into a `Task<T>` and making them asynchronous.  You could then use async calls everywhere.

> IE, for TAP calculators, it seems I need to do an "await", but for non-TAP calculators, I wouldn't.

It actually doesn't matter how this is implemented.  A "non-TAP" calculator would return `T`, and a "TAP" calculator would return `Task<T>`.  This is really the only difference - if your method is returning `Task` or `Task<T>`, you'd likely want to use `await`.  If not, you'd either want to just use the value, or wrap it in `TaskEx.Run` (making it async) so that you could use `await`.

Comment: IMO using Task/TaskEx.FromResult in the sync case would be preferable to `TaskEx.Run`

Comment: @spender It depends - if you want to make the sync calls asynchronous (though risk threading issues), Task.Run is preferrable.  If you use TaskEx.FromResult, you'll block, since that requires the result to already be computed.  Both have advantages and disadvantages.